# Notepad regexp search and replace

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone know how to using regexp within Notepad ++ search & replace tool to remove anything before ABCD and anything after.in

FROM: Test ABCD.496294$#%.intobedelete;

To: ABCD.496294$#%.in

Much appreciated

Comment: Probably not with Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by `before or after` ABCD, yes you can.

If you want to replace things before `ABCD` simply also put `ABCD` at the end of your replace box.

If you want to replace things after `ABCD` put `ABCD` at the end of your replace box

for example

toSearch:  **ABCD.*?\n**

toReplaceWith:  **ABCD_InsertContentToReplaceTextWithHere\n**

---

You might have to play around with notepad++'s regex syntax but the concept is there